# How to arrange the strings in my data frame given below in a desired order in R?

Tags: r, string, dataframe, substring

I have a data frame where the elements in one of the columns are

```
"1.cn3.ap.1"
"7.fr9.ap.3"
"4.dl.ap.2"
"5.d2.cr.1"
"4.dl.u.1"
"4.dl.ap.1"

df<- df[order(df$A),]

#this gave the following result :
"1.cn3.ap.1"
"4.dl.ap.1"
"4.dl.ap.2"
"4.dl.u.1"
"5.d2.cr.1" 
"7.fr9.ap.3"
```

But I need my data in this manner:

```
"1.cn3.ap.1"
"4.dl.u.1"
"4.dl.ap.1"
"4.dl.ap.2"
"5.d2.cr.1" 
"7.fr9.ap.3"
```

Comment: Hmm, seems to work for me if it's character. The issue is likely that your `df$A` is a factor. You can check this with `class(df$A)`. If it is a factor you could do: `df[order(as.character(df$A)),]`

Comment: @MikeH. thanks for your reply. I've made some edit in the question , i've added an element "4.dl.u.1" .. can you go through the question again ?

Comment: It would be much more helpful if you could actually specify WHAT you want to sort on rather than giving a desired order and asking us to figure it out. In your example it looks like you want to sort on (1) descending 1st digit, (2) ascending last 2 alphabetic chars, (3) descending last digit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to get what you need by splitting the data by the period, and sorting on the individual columns, then bringing the columns together again after sorting. something similar to this maybe?

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df <- df %>% 
      separate(A, into = c("part1","part2","part3","part4"), sep = "\\.") %>% 
      arrange(part1, part2, desc(part3), part4) %>% 
      unite(A, part1:part4, sep = ".")
```

Comment: thanks a lot !  that helps. But can you explain this sep =" \\."

Comment: The `separate` function uses regular expressions with the `sep` parameter. So in order to specify a period as a separator it needs to be escaped with a backslash.